# Python Doesn't return to while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, skip

I'm new with Python and I'm having a bit of trouble with my program. Whenever I input a second number that is larger than the first number "mCounter" should be set to false, and since there is a while loop, it should ask me to input the number of digits again. For some reason this doesn't happen. Whenever I input a second number that is larger than the first the program just stops.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

```
import random 
#Introduction
print('Choose the mode that you would like to enter by typing the letters in the brackets')
problem = input('Multiplication(M) Addition (A) Subtraction (S) Division (D): ')
#Multiplication
if problem == 'M' or problem == 'm':
    mCounter = False
    while mCounter == False:
        mInput1 = int(input('Enter the amount of digits you would like in the first number you are multiplying.\nThe first number should be greater or equal to the second number: '))
        mInput2 = int(input('Enter the amount of digits you would like in the second factor: '))
        mCounter = True
        if mInput2 > mInput1:
            print('The first number MUST be greater or equal to the second number. Please try again!')
            mCounter == False
        else:
            print('nothing')
```

Comment: Remove the double equals in `mCounter == False`

Answer (score 2):

To set the value of `mCounter`, do this:

```
mCounter = False
```

rather than this:

```
mCounter == False
```

The code you have there is just *comparing* the value of `mCounter` with `False`, and then ignoring the result of that comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
mCounter == False
```

you want:

```
mCounter = False
```

You need an assignment, rather than a conditional check.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `mCounter == False` doesn't change `mCounter`.  You have to use `=` for assignment.

```
if mInput2 > mInput1:
    print('The first number MUST be greater or equal to the second number. Please try again!')
    mCounter = False #<-- use = instead of ==
```